# Why I get this error "Module not found: Can't resolve"?

Tags: reactjs, import

I don't get it why am I getting this error?

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { HomeSVG, AboutSVG } from "../images/svg"

export const navLinks = [
   {
      id: "home",
      svg: <HomeSVG />,
      title: "Főoldal",
   },
   {
      id: "about",
      svg: <AboutSVG />,
      title: "Rólunk",
   },
];
```

And I'm exporting the components as well:

```
export const HomeSVG = () => {
return (
    <svg className="home-icon icon" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 122.88 114.45" imageRendering="optimizeQuality" fillRule="evenodd" clipRule="evenodd">
        <path fillRule="nonzero" d="M110.8..
    </svg>
)
```

}

And here is the file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add index.js file in your images/svg folder and re-export everything from there.

/images/svg/index.js

```js
export * from './HomeSVG'
export * from './AboutSVG'
```

Comment: Thank you man, but I solved with an easier way, I created an index.js file in image folder, put every svg file there and it works now :D